# How can run a bash script and inputs in one line

Tags: bash, executable

How can run a bash script and its inputs in one line instead of separate commands?

**my code**

```
#!/bin/bash
read input1 input2
...
```

**In terminal:**

```
bash file.sh input1 input2
```

instead of:

```
bash file.sh
input1 input2
```

Comment: You don't need read, you just refer to them as $1 and $2 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, don't use the read but use arguments.  The shell (Bash) will read through all of the arguments of a command and apply the needed rules where needed.  So, arguments can be any string i.e. "|", , or value "3" or .

BashSript arg1 arg2 ..

$0 is the name of the script
$1 and $2 are the following arguments

So.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "BashScript name: $0"
echo "Arg1: $1"
echo "Arg2: $2"
echo "All Arguments $@"
```

There is a lot of control you can apply to argument manipulation and input.  Far more then a simple question can cover.

Answer (score 0):

You can either echo the input and pipe to the script e.g.

```
cat 1.sh
read input1 input2

echo $input1
echo $input2

echo 'val1 val2' | bash 1.sh
```

or just refer to the positional arguments instead of using read:

```
cat 2.sh
echo $1
echo $2

bash 1.sh myval1 myval2
```

Comment: Duplicates should be flagged, not answered. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Also, `echo $foo` is buggy. See [BashPitfalls #14](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).